# i am not able to see 'hbase(main):001:0>' prompt and while trying 'create' command throws error

Tags: hbase

```
$ bin/hbase shell
```

HBase Shell; enter 'help' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.92.1, r1298924, Fri Mar  9 16:58:34 UTC 2012

create 'emp','n1'
create 'emp','n1'

ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException

Here is some help for this command:
Create table; pass table name, a dictionary of specifications per
column family, and optionally a dictionary of table configuration.
Dictionaries are described below in the GENERAL NOTES section.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the full path for hbase\lib to the HBASE_CLASSPATH in hbase\conf\hbase-env.sh

Personally, I set the following in my hbase-env.sh on a Windows 7 Environment + Cygwin:

```
export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/programs/hbase-0.92.1/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

The create command *create 'emp','n1'*seems to be correct.
What the error suggests is that either you have not specified the ZookeeperQuorum in your hbase-site.xml file or ZK jar is not in the classPath, try setting HBASE_HOME and HADOOP_HOME appropriately.